# Who are some writers that also had careers in chemistry?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I love chemistry, but I am interested in so many other things too. I believe it's important to have a complete intellectual life, and it always makes me happy to find examples of people who took their love for science and created great art with it. Many would be surprised at how many great authors were also chemists. Here are a few of my favourites:

- Isaac Asimov: Professor of biochemistry, Boston University School of Medicine
- Kurt Vonnegut: biochemistry major, not a successful chemist though.
- Robert M. Pirsig: biochemistry major

Can anyone help add to my list?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about chemistry.

Comment: got it. I wasn't sure whether or not this counted as "about chemistry", but I totally understand. Where is a good place to post this?

Comment: Within the chem.SE network, your best option is to come into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table). It's never a guaranteed answer, but neither is it guaranteed on main site. Otherwise, you'd have to look elsewhere because list questions are not on-topic here. I figure that [/r/chemistry](https://www.reddit.com/r/chemistry) would quite like this question.

Comment: Before this gets closed: Carl Djerassi, Primo Levi ;)

Comment: I liked the question! Although, everyone else *is* right when they say it shouldn't have been posted here :/ [ P.S-  Danke @KlausWarzecha ]

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Carl Djerassi seems interesting! Primo Levi also got mentioned on the reddit thread. Also; What about Oliver Sacks? I know he's not a chemist per se. He was a neurologist, but a he was also a very enthusiastic amateur chemist, and he wrote a book about it: Uncle Tungsten. I haven't read my copy yet, but one thing I will say is that the hardcover edition is a beautiful print. I'm looking forward to reading it.

Comment: @gannex I don't recall that I ever read anything by Oliver Sacks, but I remember that I enjoyed *Cantor's Dilemma* by Carl Djerassi a lot. Love and despair, academic misconduct,  the wonderful life of postgraduates, weird aspects of the peer-reviewing system and academic life... Anyway, all of this doesn't belong on Chem.SE, and probably not on academia either. *orthocresol* is probably right with reddit! Btw, if you can't wait for the novels, have a look at the real life on  http://retractionwatch.com/ ;)